# Question about weights of $\mathfrak{sl}_2 \mathbf{C}$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

On p. 148 of Fulton and Harris' book "Representation Theory: A First Course", they write that "Moreover, by the same token, the $V_\alpha$ that appear must form an unbroken string of numbers of the form $\beta$, $\beta+2$, $\ldots$, $\beta+2k$."

I believed this when I read it two weeks ago, but now I'm not so sure about it. They define the subspace $W = \bigoplus_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} V_{\alpha_0+2k}$, where $\alpha_0$ is any complex number appearing in the decomposition, and note that $W$ is invariant so it must be equal to $V$. That is fine, but I don't understand why some of these spaces $V_{\alpha_0+2 \ell}$ can't be zero.

Comment: I don't have the book handy but: The root elements $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ raise and lower the eigenvalues of eigenvectors of the Cartan element $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$. In particular, each $V_{\gamma+2k}$ is the image of $V_{\gamma}$ for any $\gamma$ with $V_{\gamma}$ nonzero. Images of nonzero can be zero, but preimages of nonzero cannot be zero.

Comment: @Jack: I suppose my question, then, is why your second sentence is true. The usual calculation only shows (if we denote the first matrix you wrote as $X$ and the second as $Y$) that $X(V_\gamma) \subseteq V_{\gamma+2}$ and $Y(V_\gamma) \subseteq V_{\gamma-2}$...

Comment: Another way to say it: as soon as $V_{\beta+2i}$ is zero, you have an invariant subspace ( (1) it is automatically closed under the Cartan element, (2) assuming you chose $\beta$ minimal, it closed under lowering, and (3) once you get zero it is closed under raising). Presumably $V$ is irreducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $V$ is an irreducible:

Let $\beta = \alpha_{0} + 2k$ for some positive $k$, and assume that $V_{\beta} = 0$ but $V_{\beta+2} \neq 0$, and let $v \in V_{\beta+2}$. Let $x = \begin{bmatrix} 0  & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $y = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, and note that $[x,y] = h = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Then $y \cdot v \in V_{\beta}$, so it must be $0$. That implies that the submodule of $V$ generated by $v$ lives in $V_{\beta+2}$ and higher weight spaces, so it can't be all of $V$, contradicting the fact that $V$ is irreducible.

That shows that once some $V_{\alpha_{0}+2k} = 0$ for some positive $k$, every higher weight space must be 0 as well.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. I guess I was confused because I thought F-H were claiming that it could be deduced from the fact that my $W$ was a submodule of $V$, not from looking at some other submodule (like the one you considered).